# Why ample line bundle is positive? (and recommendation about understanding the Kodaira embedding theorem)

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-space, kahler-manifolds, line-bundles

I'm beginner of Complex Geometry. Please Understand.

I'm learning the Daniel Huybrechts's Complex Geometry. I want to understand the Kodaira Embedding Theorem as soon as possible since it provoke surprise to me. But I stucked from the beginning. If possible, can someone guide a fast load map or crash course to understand the proof of Kodaira Embedding Theorem?

Anyway, I now try to understand the next underlined statement.

[image]

[image]

Anyone can explain the underlined statement more detail?

p.s. I studied Huybrechts's Complex Geometry, Chapter 3.2 Hodge Theory on Kahler Manifolds, Chapter 4.2 Connections, 4.3 Curvature..but I don't know where I should supplement to understand the underlined statement. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The underlined paragraph shows Ample implies positive. The hard part is the converse direction.

Comment: Thanks. And.. Where can i refer to understand the hard part ?

Answer (score 1):

$L$ being ample by definition implies that $L^k$ induces an embedding $f:X\to \mathbb P^n$. And $L^k=f^*(\mathcal O(1))$ by proposition 2.3.26 in Huybrechts' book. Therefore $k\cdot c_1(L)=c_1(\mathcal O(1)|_X$, this is what he meant by $c_1(L)$ is up to positive scalar the restriction Fubini-Study form. Positivity follows from a local description of $c_1(\mathcal O(1))$, it boils down to checking directly that the form is positive-definite at each point.

Comment: Let me follow your comment. First,  to show that $L$ is positive, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{O}(1)|_X = f^{*}(\mathcal{O}(1))$ is positive. But the tautological bundle  $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is positive line bundle and the pullback of positive line bundle under closed embedding is also positive?

Comment: @Plantation Yes, restriction of positive bundle is again positive. This is just because you can restrict Kahler metric (Fubini-Study) to your subvariety.